# .htaccess php seo url

Tags: .htaccess

i have problem with seo links

website.com/member/.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /member/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,15})-(.*).html$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

website.com/member/123-nickname.html working fine but i want that link:

website.com/member/123/nickname.html i trying this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /member/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,15})/(.*).html$ profile.php?lookup=$1 [L,NC]
```

url working but website looks like without .css

how to fix problem?

Comment: Well, you did not tell us anything about that css. How is it referenced? What result do those requests run into? What does your browsers console say to this?

Comment: simple .css with text, links, div, table, color, size.
browsers console says: The stylesheet http://website.com/404 was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Comment: Ah, that is valuable information. So most likely those references receive a response with an error message ... I suggest you load one of those references directly into the browser. What does it say? And what does your http server's error log file contain for those requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using relative URLs for your styles. Browser tries to find CSS file starting form the /member/123/ directory. Try setting absolute URL, or add it to a `base` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: i fixed that problem with <base href="http ://example.com"> working fine